# Facebook for .NET stopped working and skips code

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8

I'm building a Windows Phone 8 app and I want to provide users with a Facebook login. This code worked 2 days ago, but a teammate made changes and now it's not working anymore. He doesn't know what he has changed.

Logging in works fine, but getting user data is the problem. 
This is my code for getting the user info:

```
private async void GraphApi()
    {
        FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient(AccessToken);

        fbClient.GetCompleted += (o, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                        IAsyncResult message = Guide.BeginShowMessageBox(AppResources.ApplicationTitle, e.Error.Message, new string[] { AppResources.ButtonOk }, 0, MessageBoxIcon.Alert, null, null);
                        message.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
                    });

                return;
            }

            IDictionary<string, object> result = (IDictionary<string, object>)e.GetResultData();

            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    AppSettings["Username"] = (string)result["name"];
                    AppSettings["FirstName"] = (string)result["first_name"];
                    AppSettings["LastName"] = (string)result["last_name"];
                    AppSettings.Save();
                    ProfileName.Text = "Hi " + (string)result["name"];
                    FirstName.Text = "First Name: " + (string)result["first_name"];
                    FirstName.Text = "Last Name: " + (string)result["last_name"];
                });
        };

        await fbClient.GetTaskAsync("me");
    }
```

Making the Facebook client works fine but then it goes to this code: `fbClient.GetCompleted += (o, e)` and skips this and gives no error.

Any idea why this code doesn't work?

Comment: The lambda that's being added as a subscriber to the `fbClient.GetCompleted` event will not run when you're stepping through that code. You're subscribing to an event, and the code will run *when the event is fired*.

Comment: Oke thats clear. but the code still don't work

Comment: You didn't have source control tracking the change...? That's unfortunate.